# Generate Data on Request (ASP.NET MVC - HTML)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

All,

I am trying to generate user TAGS in Menu dynamically

I did the following

1. Created a "Partial View" for TAGS items and placed it inside the main menu (navigation bar)
2. Dynamically generated Tag List using TAG MODEL

My partial view has the following code

```
@{ 
MVCbootstrap.Views.Tag.TagListGenerator tagList = new MVCbootstrap.Views.Tag.TagListGenerator();
List<MVCbootstrap.Models.TagModel> Tag_List = tagList.Get_Tags_List();
}
<li class="">
<a href="javascript:;">
    <span class="title">Tags</span>
    <span class=" arrow"></span>
</a>
<span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="pg-indent"></i></span>
<ul class="sub-menu"> 
    @foreach (MVCbootstrap.Models.TagModel I in Tag_List)
    {
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">@I.Tag_name</a>                    
            </li>
    }
</ul>
</li>
```

> Now performance-wise, I think this is not correct if there are 1000
>   TAGS then the code will generate 1000 TAG ITEMS everytime a page is
>   refreshed or visited because these tags are in the navigation menu. So
>   what I want is to generate these TAGS ONLY when someone CLICKS on
>   "TAGS" HREF as below

```
<a href="javascript:;">
    <span class="title">Tags</span>
    <span class=" arrow"></span>
</a>
```

To improve the performance I want to generate TAGS only when **TAGS** or Tags Dropdown Arrow is clicked

The Web UI Looks like this with Dummy Tags data

```
public class TagListGenerator
{
    List<Models.TagModel> Tag_List = new List<Models.TagModel>(); 

    public List<Models.TagModel> Get_Tags_List()
    {
        //Send Tags List From LINQ.DB
        Tag_List.Add(new Models.TagModel() { Tag_id = 1, Tag_name = "Tag 1" });
        Tag_List.Add(new Models.TagModel() { Tag_id = 2, Tag_name = "Tag 2" });
        Tag_List.Add(new Models.TagModel() { Tag_id = 3, Tag_name = "Tag 3" });
        Tag_List.Add(new Models.TagModel() { Tag_id = 4, Tag_name = "Tag 4" });
        Tag_List.Add(new Models.TagModel() { Tag_id = 5, Tag_name = "Tag 5" });            
        return Tag_List;
    }
}
```

Web UI for Tags List looks like following, Where clicking on TAGS currently Toggles the list

[image: IMG]

Where the tag model is very simple as following

```
 public class TagModel
{
    public Int64 Tag_id { get; set; }
    public string Tag_name { get; set; }
}
```

Cheers

**RESOLVED:**

So I created an Action in my HOME controller called GetTags which returns the partial view

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetTags()
    {            
        return PartialView("~/Views/TagNavMenu");

    }
```

Then i added this in my main view

```
 <li class="">
            <a href="javascript:;" id="showtags">
                <span class="title">Tags</span>
                <span class=" arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="pg-indent"></i></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu" id="divdiv">  

            </ul>
        </li>
```

then I am using this call to render a partial view

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#showtags').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetTags',
            success: function (data) {
            $('#divdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Working now

Comment: You need to make use of AJAX here. Create a controller action which will return list of tags in JSON format and call that action via AJAX on click of "TAGS". Then create HTML on the fly when you receive list of tags from the server.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for your response, I created an Action in HOME Controller Called GetTags and I am returning PARTIAL VIEW from that action which is TAG_Menu .. It doesn't seem to be working - (please see the edited post above)

Comment: @aliusman I think you need to investigate, what happens in your browser. Go to developer tools and inspect JS-code errors and network activity. Double-check that ajax call successfully gets the result of partial view without errors and that there are no JS-errors.

Comment: Thanks @n.piskunov i was missing <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> It works now, how can i show Loading text while its loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if this helps someone else

**RESOLVED:**

So I created an Action in my HOME controller called GetTags which returns the partial view

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetTags()
    {            
        return PartialView("~/Views/TagNavMenu");

    }
```

Then i added this in my main view

```
 <li class="">
            <a href="javascript:;" id="showtags">
                <span class="title">Tags</span>
                <span class=" arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="icon-thumbnail"><i class="pg-indent"></i></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu" id="divdiv">  

            </ul>
        </li>
```

then I am using this call to render a partial view

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#showtags').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetTags',
            success: function (data) {
            $('#divdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Working now

Answer (score 1):

> It works now, how can i show Loading text while its loading?

You are able to place your loading message just before ajax request. For example like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#showtags').on('click', function () {
        $('#divdiv').html('<p>Loading... {or place any other html}</p>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetTags',
            success: function (data) {
            $('#divdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```